# Accessing sub key of dict in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionnaries of the following format:

```py
myList = [
    {'keyA': {'key1': 'valueA1_1',
              'key2': 'valueA2_1'},
     'keyB': 'valueB_1',
    },
    {'keyA': {'key1': 'valueA1_2',
              'key2': 'valueA2_2'},
     'keyB': 'valueB_2',
    }
]
```

I want to output a list of shape: `outputlist = ['valueA2_1 - valueB_1', 'valueA2_2 - valueB_2']`

What I did was the following:
`outputlist = [x["keyA"]['key1'] + " - " + x["keyB"] for x in myList]`
But this results in a TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Though accessing a value at a time works pretty fine:
`myList[0]["keyA"]["key1"]` outputs the proper needed value: "valueA2_1"

Any way to access "nested dictionnaries"?
Thanks.

Comment: With your sample list and code, no such error can be reproduced (if `myList` is changed to `mylist` in list comprehension). Can you show your actual code that produces that error?

Comment: Infact the issue was that some of the dicts within the list had empty keys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a typo in the collection names.
Do you have my**l**ist collection in your code only? Or also my**L**ist?

This construction works pretty well, by the way.

```
outputlist = [x["keyA"]['key1'] + " - " + x["keyB"] for x in mylist]
```